# Python Compare overlap of multiple dictionaries of ranges

Tags: python, dictionary, range

I have several set of files I would like to compare based on an identifier column, start value and end value. Each file has the following layout:
Ex.

```
A    200    900
A    300    1200
B    100    700
B    900    1000
```

The identifiers and values vary in each file and I would like to compare the overlap for between 2 to 4 sets of these files. So if another File has "A    150    1000" I would get and overlap between the two files.

For example, if I put in 4 files with 100 rows each I would like to know the number of overlaps (or non-overlaps) between each of the files.

```
FileA only =
FileB only = 
FileC only = 
FileD only = 
FileA and FileB = 
FileA and FileC =
FileA and FileD =
FileA, FileB and FileC =
....
```

My code currently looks like:

```
def ReadFile(FileName, LineCount, Ranges)
    with open(FileName, "r") as FileName:
        LineCount = 0
        for Line in FileName:
            if LineCount==0:
                print "Skipping First Line"
            else:
                Line = Line.strip("\n").split("\t")
                Chr = Line[0]
                Start = int(Line[1])
                End = int(Line[2])
                ranges[Ident].append((Start, End))
            LineCount+=1

FileNum = int(raw_input("Number of Files for Comparison"))
rangesA = rangesB = rangesC = rangesD =defaultdict(list)

ReadFile(FileA, LineCountA, rangesA)
ReadFile(FileB, LineCountB, rangesB)
if FileNum >= 3:
    ReadFile(FileC, LineCountC, rangesC)
if FileNum >= 4:
    ReadFile(FileD, LineCountD, rangesD)
```

I'm a bit stuck when if comes to the comparison...

Comment: Could you be more specific by what you mean by __"So if another File has "A 150 1000" I would get and overlap between the two files"__? Is that based on a numeric range or simple text comparison or something else?

Comment: I am treating the the values as ranges with a start and end value. So that one of the ranges for "A" in fileA would be 200-900 and a range for "A" in FileB would be 150-1000. I then want to compare how many of the ranges for A overlap with ranges in FileB, which in the above example would be one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to get for each file the ranges in this format:

```
rangesForFile0[
    ("A", 100, 1500, "file0"),
    ("A", 400, 1000, "file0"),
    ...
]
```

Then, put all ranges in one list:

```
allRanges = rangesForFile0 + rangesForFile1 + ...
```

Then sort the list by the label, then by start value (given the order of fields in tuples, this should be enough):

```
allRanges.sort()
```

Then go through the list of ranges and for each range check which other ranges it overlaps with and note from which files those other ranges are:

```
def rangesOverlap(x1, x2, y1, y2):
    return (x1 <= y2) and (y1 <= x2)

fileSetToRangesMap = {}
for i, r in enumerate(allRanges):
    fileSet = set([r[3]])
    x1 = r[1]
    x2 = r[2]
    for j, r2 in enumerate(allRanges):
        y1 = r2[1]
        y2 = r2[2]
        if (r[0] == r2[0]) and rangesOverlap(x1, x2, y1, y2):
            fileSet.add(r2[3])
    fileSetToRangesMap.setdefault(frozenset(fileSet), []).append(r)
```

After this, the fileSetToRangesMap should contain as keys all the different sets of files that have overlaps while the values will be arrays of ranges that have overlapping counterparts in this set of files. The keys containing single file would list those ranges that are unique in that file.

The above will treat ranges (100, 400) and (200, 500) as overlapping. If you only need to count the ranges where one range fully includes another range from a different file, then the order of files becomes important and you would need to build a more sophisticated directional relationship graph between the ranges and, thus, files

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm just running into one problem when trying to implement your solution and I'm not sure what's going wrong. For instance if File A has 188 lines and File B has 121 line, when I run the program I get: `A:    167,      B:    111,      A_B:    31`

Comment: It is difficult to know where the problem is without knowing how do you get to the quoted output. The latest version of your code would be helpful as would be (possibly small) examples of files A and B where the problems show.

Comment: I used the code exactly as described above but the discrepancies are as I will put below (first number is the output, second is what I should get): `A:     2245     2245,     B:     629     671,     C:     548     760,     A_B:     42     42,     B_C:     149     165,     A_C:     47     47,     A_B_C:     16     16 `

Comment: There was an error in the loop that searched for other ranges that overlap with the current range. Edited the answer to fix it.